# Tooltip with scrollbar - disappears on scroll

Tags: css, angular, scrollbar

I have an Angular tooltip directive on an element. As long as I hover on that element the tooltip is showing, and when I click that element the tooltip stays open, until I click outside of it or I scroll the page.

I'm trying to add max-height and overflow:scroll when the tooltip gets too big. If I click on the element and then scroll on the tooltip, it starts scrolling correctly, then disappears.

Is there a way to solve this with CSS? Or do I need to change the directive?

Comment: I suggest you don't use a tooltip design for a scrollable info popup. if it were me I would have brought it with the design team and create a new popup component for longer info.

Comment: Maybe you should check `z-index`, `overflow` or 'positin:absolute'. If you share detailed code, then, I may give more answer.

Comment: I figured it out, I actually had an event listener for the scroll event which was hiding the tooltip. Thank you!